# Two compares in one if / else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to find an answer for a pretty simple question.

**Is it possible to ask 2 things in 1 if / else  statement?**

For example:

```
if($a>$b AND isset($c))
    return TRUE;
```

I understand it is possible to write it like:

```
if ($a>$b)
{
 if (isset($c))
    return TRUE;
}
```

I am looking for something easier and less messy to code. I am up for any advises.
Thanks.

Comment: This is basic PHP 101: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: @Andurit please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `&&` operator :

```
if($a > $b && isset($c)){
     return true;
}
```

**Note**: It will check that both conditions are true, if yes then only `if block` works. If you want that anyone of them true will lead to `if block` execution then go for `||` operator.

Comment: Thank you for answer, looks it was easier then I expect. As soon as more people answer correctly I try to be fair and mark your answer as correct because it's the first one and well explained :) (just waiting until it let me do it )

Comment: thanks. :):). glad to help you. and thanks to be so much fair. thank you.

Comment: @Andurit Please vote-up also my answer. thanks. if it is possible.

Comment: I already did, you have -1 from someone else, thats why its 0 together

Answer (score 2):

Yes we have an `&&` operator for this:

```
if($a > $b && isset($c)){
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** it is possible. You can use `&&` operator which will require both the conditions to be `true` so no need of that nested `if` . Just do -

```
if($a>$b && isset($c))
    return TRUE;
```

Comment: Well if you already give OP an answer why don't you explain what you did in your code and what it does? Only with the code he doesn't know much more than before. (But I doubt it that you will update it..)

Comment: @Rizier123 Updated the answer. Hope it is more clear now and explains the code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can as

```
if($a>$b && isset($c)){
    return TRUE;
}
```

or

```
if($a>$b AND isset($c)){
    return TRUE;
}
```

They do the same thing, but **&&** has higher precedence than **AND**.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

```
if($a>$b && isset($c)
return TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tou can do even with AND / OR opperators. Like:

```
if($v == 'asd' AND $b = 'asdsd') echo "Yes";
```